# remove dotted line when drawing a transparent

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am simply developing a drawing application. I need to draw a transparent line, whenever I draw I get dots appearing on the line.

how do I rectify this problem? how do I remove the dots from the line?

my code is below here

```
- (UIImage *)drawSmoothLine  // stright line correct
{
    CGPoint mid1    = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2    = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGSize screenSize = self.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    [self.layer drawInContext:context];


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);

    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, drawColor.CGColor);


    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return ret;
}
```

[image: Ipad screen shot of bug]
<sub>(source: [4shared.com](http://dc471.4shared.com/img/3_9Uo8qT/s3/Screen_shot_2012-06-15_at_1564.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIBezierPath` 
Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927702/getting-a-smooth-bezier-path-using-catmullromspline) for reference and modify according to your needs. 
Hope this helps you.